# Dynamic array - reading

Tags: c++, c++11

```
 class Sesion
{
private:
         int wymiar = 2;
         int **tablica = new int *[wymiar];
         int licznik = 0;

    void save(int x, int y)
    {
            for (int i = 0; i < wymiar; i++)
                    tablica[i] = new int[wymiar];

            tablica[0][licznik] = x;
            tablica[1][licznik] = y;

            licznik++;
    }

    void open()
    {
            for (int i = 0; i < licznik; i++)
            {
                cout << tablica[0][i] << endl;
            }
    }
}
```

I dont know how to read value in `open()` because im getting weird numbers there.

In `save()` everything works perfect. Im must to save x and y in unlimited array and then read these values from it.

I know i can use Vector but i need to do it using Dynamic Array

Comment: Can you post the code you are using that produces the strange behavior?

Answer (score 3):

You are complicating you life unnecessarily. Managing memory allocation/deallocation by yourself, in a safe manner, is going to be a PITA. Not to mention that your code is also affected by memory leak.

I've also noticed that you are always saving pair of `int`s. You should be using [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) or a custom struct/class, in conjunction with an [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Here's an example:

```
class Sesion {
private:
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> tablica;
public:
    void save(int x, int y) {
        tablica.emplace_back(x, y);
    }

    void open() {
        for (auto p : tablica)
            std::cout << std::get<0>(p) << ',' << std::get<1>(p) << '\n';
    }
};
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f25fd589fe9ae6dd)

Answer (score 0):

consider using `std::vector`, e.g.

```
class Sesion
{
private:
    struct Point { int x, y; };

    std::vector<Point> points_;

public:
    void save(int x, int y)
    {
        points_.push_back( Point{x, y} );
    }

    void open()
    {
        for ( Point const& point : points_ )
        {
            cout << point.x << " " << point.y << endl;
        }
    }
};
```